# How to define an additional dynamic link for Colorbox-Images?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have a one-pager with a lot of images and some galleries. These are triggered to show up in a colorbox-overlay (with Drupal, Colorbox-Plugin), when clicked on the images. So far so good, working great.

Now i want to have additional icons attached to the images and gallerys (for redundancy) to open these images in the colorbox as well.

For my test-gallery i got this working:

```
<script>
(function($){
    $('.field-name-field-slideshow-trigger').append('<div id="bgShowOverlay"></div>').css("cursor","pointer");
            $('#bgShowOverlay').click(function() {
                $("a[rel='gallery-all']").colorbox({open:true});
             });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Now for the single images (no gallery) i need to specify this somehow for the dynamically created image-links. I dont know how to contruct this part

```
$('#bgImageOverlay').click(function() {
                $("a[rel=?????]").colorbox({open:true});
             });
```

to get it working with my images, that have an rel-attribute like this:

```
rel="gallery-field_collection_item-60"
```

I hope my question is clear enough, please excuse my bad english.
Any help highly appreciated!

EDIT:

I found out that

> "a[rel='gallery-all']"

does not work (like i was expecting) when i have more than one gallery on my one-pager. All images that are in galleries show in the one i open in the colorbox.

I'm looking for a way to give some kind of differentiation to the link.

How can i form the script, that it takes the dynamically created galleries into account?

Answer (score 2):

This perhaps?

```
$("a[rel^=gallery]").colorbox({open:true});
```

I'm don't really have a clear enough idea of how you have things laid out to give a definitive answer.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for my belated answer. What you gave me here works great for all links that start with "gallery". That was new for me and i learned something. But I'm looking for something that takes the ID of the image into account the links are structured like this: 'gallery-field_collection_item-60' or 'gallery-field_collection_item-23'